Azure Logic App Error: VSCode reports 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'credentials2')'
I'm encountering an error while working with Azure Logic Apps in Visual Studio Code. Whenever I attempt to open the designer, I receive the following message: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'credentials2').'

I suspect this error might be related to recently deleted Logic Apps(Standard Plan), but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Could it be a cache issue or something else entirely?
I am using VScode's Azure Logic Apps (Standard) extension. BTW, I do not have any Azure Logic Apps (Standard Plan) atm but I do have  Azure Logic Apps(Consumption plan).

Have you created the logic app standard workflow locally in vs code? If so then try to delete it and recreate

Also you will get this error when you are not signed-in correctly in Azure

After creating a new logic app in VSCode, when I clicked 'use connector from Azure', the designer did not load. However, if I sign-out from Vscode and skip 'connector from Azure' in another new Logic app, the designer loads without any issues!

I performed a clean installation of VSCode and reinstalled the Azure Logic Apps (Standard) extension. This resolved the issue. Just to confirm, although I can still see errors under the function app and logic app, they do not prevent the designer from loading :)
